Refresh materialized view in oracle on request
I have a materialized view that refreshes every day at 9 AM, and working (configuration was added in Toad).
Now, I'm attempting to refresh the materialized view on demand. For this purpose, the following code is used:
BEGIN 
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('your_materialized_view_name'); 
END;

Let's say I run this code at 2 in the afternoon. But here's the problem: after I run it, the view starts updating itself at 2 PM every day instead of 9 AM like before.
Is there a way to make sure it keeps updating at 9 AM, no matter when I manually update it?
Can we add something to the code to make that happen? I saw a possibility doing it via 'CREATE_JOB' but hopping there is another way
BEGIN 
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('your_materialized_view_name'); 
-- Additional code to enforce the 9 AM schedule
END;



How was the materialized view told to refresh every day at 9am?  My guess is that you specified the next as sysdate + 1 which would refresh 24 hours after the last refresh rather than trunc(sysdate + 1) + interval '9' hour which would refresh tomorrow at 9am regardless of when the last refresh finished.

@Jusing Cave thx for the reply.
In toad => alter metalized view , you can set the interval and add the time ect.
in my case i used  09AM
and 'SYSDATE + 1'

@JustinCave, thx for the support i changed it to trunc(sysdate + 1) + interval '9' hour and works as expected! Many Thx for the help
